# How to separate a file to different file using awk

Tags: awk, extract

I have a dataset with few columns but I want to separate it to a new file when column 1 has an even number. Column 1 format is `M1 *`, and here it has odd number (1).

Dataset:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 
M1 * 2 3 
M3 * 4 2 
M2 * 1 5 
M6 * 1 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ awk '!(substr($1,2)%2)' infile > new_file
$ cat new_file
Var1 Var2 Var3
M2 * 1 5
M6 * 1 6
```

Comment: @EdMorton - Thanks for pointing this out, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @EdMorton - Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With grep:

```
$ grep '^[^[:blank:]]*[02468][[:blank:]]' infile
M2 * 1 5
M6 * 1 6
```

This gets all the lines where the character before the first space is even, i.e., the first column ends with an even number.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '$1~/[02468]$/' file   

M2 * 1 5 
M6 * 1 6
```

checks whether the last digit of the first field is one of the evens.

To add the header

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || $1~/[02468]$/' file

Var1 Var2 Var3 
M2 * 1 5 
M6 * 1 6
```